# Search bug: automatic string-tag conversion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, tag-search

Searching

`[batch] database` turns to `[batch] [database]`

but

`[batch] file` don't changes.

Worth saying that both [database](/questions/tagged/database) and [file](/questions/tagged/file) are existing tags.

Not sure which one is a bug, but my logic tells me one of them must be

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search terms don't get automatically turned into tags unless they're in the top 60 tags.

[database](/questions/tagged/database) is a top tag, [file](/questions/tagged/file) isn't.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it's supposed to work, converting top tags only.  However converting *some* of the terms to tags and messing up your search was extremely confusing.

Though this particular example doesn't change, we will no longer convert terms to tags unless we can convert **all** of them to tags.  This supports the case of `C#` redirecting to the tag page, but not causing a query like `Test configuration with IIS` to become `Test configuration with [iis]` on Server Fault.  Real searches were being harmed with that behavior.