# Inconsistent search result behavior for different keywords

Tags: support, search

When I search for C# or SQL in SO, it comes up with the newest C# or SQL questions. But when I search for something like 'SSIS', it comes up with relevance and displays both Questions and Answers, even though SSIS has a tag. This seems like inconsistent behavior. Do some tags have different search result behavior than others?

Comment: You can force the search to see something as a tag by using `[..]` around it. Search for `[ssis]` instead.

Comment: I don't understand why C# or SQL does it automatically and SSIS doesn't.

Comment: I think it's the size of the tag. Top X tags auto-convert to tag searches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top 40 tags *only* are auto-converted to tags, because people typing "C#" and hitting enter in the search box is a *very* common search, same for "Java", etc.  There's also a little magic trying combos, e.g. "sql server" redirects to "sql-server" because the combined of hyphenated terms are a top tag.  The other common case there was "vb .net", but it's generically supported.

We support this use case but not all the way down for all tags, because when you get to a term with a small tag set it's usually much more prevalent than the limited scope of posts actually dedicating a tag to it, it's commonly just a word in the post in those cases.

Comment: If tags are auto-converted, why is this then?:  [Search ignores most obvious result (upvoted question with dozens of incoming links)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165309)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Tags are now only auto-converted when [all terms can be converted to tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133941/search-bug-automatic-string-tag-conversion/166166#166166).

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I've found a performance friendly solution to the root cause there - it'll go out in a build this afternoon.