# Some search words get converted to tags

Tags: support, search, tag-search

On meta I just tried to searched for

```
support stackoverflow
```

and wondered why it got converted to a tag search

```
[support] [stackoverflow]
```

Is this intended behaviour and if so on what conditions? I tried other search terms that (luckily) did not get converted to tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer below was correct from 2009 to 2013, but an update was made after the blog post I cited that made it so tags in search terms won't be converted unless **all** words in the search can be converted.

**Source:** [Nick Craver's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166166/1288), and @V2Blast's comment below.

---

Only the top 60 tags on the site you're searching will automatically be converted. [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) are currently the [#3 and #6 tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) respectively on Meta, so they get converted when you enter them as search terms. You can circumvent this conversion by putting your search term in quotes. Example: "support" or "stackoverflow".

> Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be auto-converted to tag searches. So if you enter
>
> c++ entities
>
> it will convert to
>
> `[c++]` entities
>
> automagically on your behalf.

**Source:** [Stack Overflow Search – Now 61% Less Crappy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)

Comment: That does not work as decribed. Try `support something`. It does **not** get converted to `[support]  something`. It seems currently all search words must be in the top 40 tags. I guess that is why I never saw the autoconversion in my searches until now.

Comment: @juergend You're right. The [c++ entities](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+entities) example I quoted doesn't work on SO the way it's described either. I'm looking to see if this is an intentional update.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: For future reference, Nick Craver mentioned it in [this 2013 answer to a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166166/335251): "we will no longer convert terms to tags unless we can convert **all** of them to tags. This supports the case of `C#` redirecting to the tag page, but not causing a query like `Test configuration with IIS` to become `Test configuration with [iis]` on Server Fault."

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you for the update. I've been looking in to this the whole time! ;)