# How can I bypass automatic string-tag conversion?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, search, localization

On [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour), I wanted to make a search for questions related to the conflict in Ukraine.

There are many questions on the topic which don't have the tag *[ukraine]* attached to them, but on searching for the keyword Ukraine, the system auto converts this to a tag search thereby excluding instances of the string without the tag.

As an answer to [this previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133941/search-bug-automatic-string-tag-conversion) (Search bug: automatic string-tag conversion) marked as *[status-by-design]* explains:

> This is how it's supposed to work, converting top tags only.

How can I bypass this inconvenience and search for all posts relating to a topic regardless of them possessing the tag or not? I.e. search for string and tag, or string or tag separately, either works. (using the search bar, not a code-heavy SEDE query, beyond my skillset.)

Blind as to if there's an answer or not, I'll make this a feature request in case it's not possible by means of the standard search bar on a site, i.e., can we have the facility to do this, please?

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your keyword in double quotes: [searching for `"ukraine"`](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ukraine%22) bypasses the tag conversion:

[image]

though the first hit *not* tagged [ukraine] takes some scrolling: [Why are PiS and Fidesz split over Russia (and Ukraine)?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69474/why-are-pis-and-fidesz-split-over-russia-and-ukraine)

Comment: Simple, neat solution that only myself wouldn't have thought of using :)